# Sharepoint 2013 : REST API working in browser but not with javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint 2013 server and I can use REST API's in browser which works fine.
But the problem is when I try to call these API's in javascript/ajax it gives 401 authentication error.

I have googled a lot on this but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: did you find any solution ??